# Pinterest Rich Pins and Escaped Fragment (#!)

Tags: backbone.js, phantomjs, pinterest, hashbang

I have a backbonejs website that sets and unsets meta information for specific pieces of content that need to be shared out, and cooperates with a phantomjs server ([example](http://backbonetutorials.com/seo-for-single-page-apps/)) by using the `#!` standard put out by google.

Currently my content is passing Facebook's open graph debugger, Google webmaster URL tester, and Twitter's card validator tool, but it seems like Pinterest isn't adhering to the same `#!` standard as the other three big wigs.

Is this true, and if so is there anyway to create Pinterest Rich Pins with content from a dynamic single page app?

Comment: Hm we got Pinterest working on here which we built in Backbone but not exactly sure what rich pins are? http://artofthetrench.burberry.com/gallery/d/erdem-denkli-photographed-in-trench-coat-by-jon-cardwell-in-antalya-3a995e7a-d08e-11e3-bb01-611ea1f2f774